# Spring-MVC : Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [servlet-context.xml]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cometd, spring-scheduled

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to use , but whenever I do so, I get an error as mentioned below. I have checked other links for similar problems, but they were not useful with all the options it had. So I am posting a new question.

As the project is big, the XML files are big too. Please note, when I add , my @Scheduled methods are firing, but servlet is throwing load exception, without that, they are not firing.

Error code :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [servlet-context.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)

ROOT CAUSE
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
```

Here goes my servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>


    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
   </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.max_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.timeout">1000</beans:prop>
                <!--    <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <task:annotation-driven />

      <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"  ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Person beans being here -->
    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="LoginServiceImpl"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>

    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
                class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters" ref="jsonMessageConverter"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

</beans:beans>
```

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

   <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

     <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
         <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
     </security:session-management>


    </security:http>

    <!-- Rest authentication, don't edit, delete, add-->
    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">

    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain filters="persistencefilter,authenticationfilter" pattern="/login"/>
        <security:filter-chain filters="persistencefilter,logoutfilter" pattern="/logout"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**" filters="persistencefilter,restfilter" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistencefilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

    <bean id="authenticationfilter" class="com.journaldev.spring.utility.AuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="pass"/>
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="user"/>
        <property name="postOnly" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthSuccessHandler" class="com.journaldev.spring.utility.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <bean id="myLogoutHandler" class="com.journaldev.spring.utility.MyLogoutHandler"/>

    <bean id="logoutfilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">

        <constructor-arg index="0" value="/"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
                    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"/>
                    <property name="clearAuthentication" value="true"/>
                </bean>
                <bean id="myLogoutHandler" class="com.journaldev.spring.utility.MyLogoutHandler"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>

    <bean id="restfilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <security:filter-invocation-definition-source>
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:filter-invocation-definition-source>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Rest authentication ends here-->

    <!-- queries to be run on data -->
    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Database management for remember-me -->
    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

If there is anything else necessary, like web.xml or so, kindly let me know. I am having this problem since many days, but no solution on net. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

*Edit*

root-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


</beans>
```

web.xml (Complete)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"
        >
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/views/error/403.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/403</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



   <!-- <filter>
       <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>ExpiresByType text/html</param-name>
            <param-value>access plus 1 seconds</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType text/javascript</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType font/truetype</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType font/opentype</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>ExpiresByType image/svg+xml</param-name>
          <param-value>access plus 10 weeks</param-value>
       </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>-->


    <!-- Cometd servlet mappings -->

</web-app>
```

BayeuxInitializer :

```
package com.journaldev.spring.chat;

import org.cometd.annotation.ServerAnnotationProcessor;
import org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer;
import org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

@Component
public class BayeuxInitializer implements DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor, ServletContextAware
{
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
    private ServerAnnotationProcessor processor;

    @Inject
    private void setBayeuxServer(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer)
    {
        this.bayeuxServer = bayeuxServer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {

        this.processor = new ServerAnnotationProcessor(bayeuxServer);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("Bayeux in PreDestroy");
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException
    {
        processor.processDependencies(bean);
        processor.processConfigurations(bean);
        processor.processCallbacks(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException
    {
        return bean;
    }

    public void postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException
    {
        processor.deprocessCallbacks(bean);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BayeuxServer bayeuxServer()
    {
        return new BayeuxServerImpl();
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        servletContext.setAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE, bayeuxServer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us where your `security-applicationContext.xml` is loaded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : What do you mean by loaded? The directory structure??

Comment: Where have you declared `security-applicationContext.xml` to be used for your application?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I have added my web.xml, where I am using that file in contextConfigLocation. I am not calling/loading/anything the security-applicationContext.xml from Java.

Comment: Ok, now show us what is in `root-context.xml`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis added in main post.

Comment: So the issue is that, for whatever reason, you can only have one `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean defined in a context.  `<task:annotation-driven />` declares one, but I can't find anything else in your XML configuration that declares another. Maybe you have something in your packages that gets component scanned.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I have component scan in servlet-context itself like this     <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>

Comment: Right, that package hierarchy might contain something that declares a `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean. Or maybe some `<security:...>` element does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I dont understand what you said last, but can you tell me how to fix this problem? Its kinda annoying.

Comment: You have to find which configuration element of yours defines a `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean. You can only have one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I don't even know what it is, only Cometd which I have uses Async is what i know. I have cometd, I am pasting the BayeuxInitializer along with entire web.xml

Comment: I think I know. Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to happen while loading the context for your `DispatcherServlet`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

which you've defined to load both the `servlet-context.xml` and `security-applicationContext.xml`. **But** `security-applicationContext.xml` already imports `servlet-context.xml`. So you gets all its beans twice. One of those bean is `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, which can only appear once in the context.

So get rid of `servlet-context.xml` in the above declaration.

Also, you are currently defining both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` to load the XML context configurations. Why?

See here: [What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was learning at the time I created my first project with above config, and it was working ever since, so I was using it. I am home now, I will go in office tomorrow and try this out first thing in the morning. I am reading the link you gave, if there is any alternative solution, kindly let me know.

Comment: @WeareBorg Alternative solution to what? Spring web app can have both a root (`ContextLoaderListener`) context and a servlet (`DispatcherServlet`) context. You shouldn't have them both initialized from the same configuration.

Comment: Ok. I will change the configuration first thing in morning and post a comment here, thank you so much for your efforts.. I will keep you updated... :-)

Comment: That solved the problem, one more such problem which is lingering around, I can use your help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094752/spring-mvc-spring-spring-security-unable-to-get-online-user-from-sessionregis